# Getting Bad request while creating folders on nextcloud through MKCOL when folder name contains specific words like Hazlo

Tags: nextcloud, sabredav

```
<?php
include_once("vendor/autoload.php");

$settings = array(
    'baseUri' =>  '<removed>',
    'userName' => '<removed>',
    'password' => '<removed>'
);
 $client = new Sabre\DAV\Client($settings);

 $f_name = ' Hazlo ';

 $folder_name = '16-843-82 MV ATC_BLHI Hazlo to PPC';


 //$response = $client->request('MOVE', $folder_name, '',
 //array('Destination' => '/remote.php/webdav/'. $f2));



 $response = $client->request('MKCOL', $f_name, null, array());

  print_r($response);
```

?>

I am trying to create a folder using MKCOL on next cloud but it is getting failed if folder contains certain keywords like HAZLO so if folder name is AT HAZLO it won't work but if contains word like AT MANISH then it works

Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem.

I can't make a dir with " H".

" h", "_H", "-H", etc have no problem, but " H" it's impossible!